# Spark-Streaming broadcast variable to custom receiver

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I created an application which is using Spark-Streaming with the custom receiver Google Pub/Sub.

I hit my performance limit and interested to drop messages without processing it. I had an idea to `store()` sub of reading messages
I used **apache/bahir** receiver

```scala
                val pullResponse = client.projects().subscriptions().pull(subscriptionFullName, pullRequest).execute()
                val receivedMessages = pullResponse.getReceivedMessages.asScala.toList
                Utils.LOG.info(s"receivedMessages from PUB/SUB ${receivedMessages.size}")
                rateLimiter.acquire(receivedMessages.size)
                var factor: Int = 0
                if (dropFactorBroad != null) {
                    factor = dropFactorBroad.value
                } else {
                    Utils.LOG.info("dropFactorBroad is null")
                }
                val endIndex = if (factor > receivedMessages.length) receivedMessages.length else factor
                val messagesToStore = receivedMessages.slice(0, receivedMessages.length - endIndex)

                store(messagesToStore.map(x => {
                      val sm = new SparkPubsubMessage
                      sm.message = x.getMessage
                      sm
                  })
                  .iterator)

                val ackRequest = new AcknowledgeRequest()
                ackRequest.setAckIds(receivedMessages.map(x => x.getAckId).asJava)
                client.projects().subscriptions().acknowledge(subscriptionFullName, ackRequest).execute()
```

`dropFactorBroad` - is Broadcast variable which is updated on every `onBatchCompleted`(unpersisted and created again)

It is not working, I'm getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mag.ingester.ReceiverDropFactorBroadcaster.value(ReceiverDropFactorBroadcaster.scala:20)
    at com.mag.pubSubReceiver.PubsubReceiver.receive(PubsubInputDStream.scala:260)
    at com.mag.pubSubReceiver.PubsubReceiver$$anon$1.run(PubsubInputDStream.scala:244)
```

`ReceiverDropFactorBroadcaster` is dropFactorBroad

How can I control the receive store?
Should I kill receivers change the variable and start it again? (How can it be done?)

Thanks